# how can i print 11 numbers in 2 div,in each div i need 8 names(4 td's in each row)second div from 9,how can i do this?

Tags: html, jsp

```
<%
        int apps = 11;
        int noOfDiv = apps % 3, k, m;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            out.println("<div>");
            out.println("<table>");
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                for (k = 1; k <= 4; k++) {
                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println("" + k + "");
                    out.println("</td>");
                }
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</div>");
        }
    %>
```

for this i'm getting output as

```
1234
1234
```

in div1

```
1234
1234
```

in div2 ,

but i need

```
1234
5678
```

in div1 and

```
9 10 11
```

in div2 if i have total 11 numbers

Answer (score 0):

It is because you prints `k` for `k` = 1 to 4, and to correct use an extra variable say capital `K = 1` before any  loop, then replace:

```
for (k = 1; k <= 4; k++) // print 1 to 4
```

as:

```
int noOfDiv = apps % 3, k, m, K = 1;   // Added K = 1
// rest of your codes ... 
for (k = K; k <= K + 3; k++){
    // code you  already have to print small `k`
    K += 4;
 }
```

Comment: I'm unable to get it,could you please modify my above code and show me the total code,i'm new to programming,thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3297398 My answer is very simple, add one more variable say `K =1` and change for-loop as suggested,  Read-comments in my answer.

Comment: It is printing numbers from 1 to 16,but when i have apps =11 then it should end at 11 not to exceed more than that,where should i change?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using following code;

```
<%

    int apps = 11;
    int noOfDiv = apps % 3, k, m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        out.println("<div>");
        out.println("<table>");
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            int temp = (j-1)*4 +1;
            for (k = temp; k <= temp+3; k++) {
                out.println("<td>");
                out.println("" + k + "");
                out.println("</td>");
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");


    }
    out.println("<div><table><tr><td>" + (apps - 2) + "</td><td>" + (apps - 1) + "</td><td>" + apps + "</td></tr></table></div>");

%>
```

Comment: `k <= k+3;`  will be always true if `k` is positive. You need `k <= temp + 3;`

Comment: Not sure missing `;` at `temp = (j-1)*4 +1`  btw what is this condition? his div starts before `j` loop.

Comment: temp for not repeating numbers 1 2 3 4 and 1 2 3 4 again. k value must have start value with parameter row

Comment: i need only 2 rows in a single div,when 8 reaches in second row of first div,reaming elements has to print in next div,can you guide me now?

Comment: But in next div OP @user3297398 need 9 10 11... You are printing same values in all divs.

Comment: yes,what Grijesh Chauhan told is right,i need 9 to remaining elements in next div.